# APT totally broken

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

i am on Ubuntu 14.04 and my `apt` is totally broken.

The problem started with `grub-pc` package and now continues , along with that package, with `libuuid1:amd64` package.

intsallation of `libuuid1:amd64` package ( using `apt` or `dpkg` ) gives error

```
package libuuid1:amd64 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6 cannot be configured because libuuid1:i386 is at a different version (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4)
```

earlier atleast, whenever i got updates, the other packages got installed. Now, no [ackages get installed at all!

Please help. I cannot install or update anything!

---

Result of `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
nirmik@nirmik-esds:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  kodi kodi-bin
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apparmor firefox firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer google-chrome-beta
  libapparmor-perl libapparmor1 linux-firmware openssh-client openssh-server
  openssh-sftp-server ssh-askpass-gnome thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support
  tzdata tzdata-java xul-ext-ubufox y-ppa-manager yad
19 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/149 MB of archives.
After this operation, 15.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package libuuid1:amd64 (--configure):
 package libuuid1:amd64 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6 cannot be configured because libuuid1:i386 is at a different version (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libblkid1:amd64:
 libblkid1:amd64 depends on libuuid1 (>= 2.16); however:
  Package libuuid1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libblkid1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmount1:amd64:
 libmount1:amd64 depends on libblkid1 (>= 2.17.2); however:
  Package libblkid1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmount1:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

output of `find /etc/apt/ -name "*.list" -exec bash -c 'printf "\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" "========" "$1" "========"; cat "$1"' _ {} \;`

```
========
/etc/apt/sources.list
========
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-thunderbird-next-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-next/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/thunderbird-next/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-indicators-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/indicators/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/indicators/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ravefinity-project-ppa-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ravefinity-project/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/leolik-leolik-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/leolik/leolik/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/leolik/leolik/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome-beta.list
========
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/team-xbmc-ppa-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/noobslab-apps-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tsbarnes-indicator-keylock-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tsbarnes/indicator-keylock/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tsbarnes/indicator-keylock/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/indicator-multiload-daily-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/indicator-multiload/daily/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vlijm-qle-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/vlijm/qle/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/vlijm/qle/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/libreoffice-ppa-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

========
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/amandeepgrewal-notifyosdconfig-trusty.list
========
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/amandeepgrewal/notifyosdconfig/ubuntu trusty main
```

Output of `apt-cache policy libuuid1`

```
libuuid1:
  Installed: 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6
  Candidate: 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6
  Version table:
 *** 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: what is the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @orvi it completes without any error

Comment: then how APT is broken ? anyway from the output i found that it's version case . http://pkgs.org/debian-sid/debian-main-i386/libuuid1_2.26.2-9_i386.deb.html download it from here and build it manually. Let me know if it works

Comment: @orvi  its broken because upgrade or install command fails. Ive edited the question

Comment: okay whatever . Now do it manually.

Comment: @orvi   by buid manually you mean? coz i only see deb files there

Comment: downloaded Debian (Ubuntu) package (.deb).Open Terminal and type

`sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`

Comment: anyway I found another interesting thing in your code. Please check it . there's an error your upgrade. Fix it too

Comment: @orvi    i am not able to fix it! how do i? also, manually installing the amd64 package gives same error of i386 variant being on other version. i also tried installing the i386 version, but then it ( obviously) gives architecture not matching error

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `find /etc/apt/ -name "*.list" -exec bash -c 'printf "\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" "========" "$1" "========"; cat "$1"' _ {} \;`

Comment: @A.B. done. Please check

Comment: Ok, give me the output of `apt-cache policy libuuid1`

Comment: @A.B.  here it is http://paste.ubuntu.com/12107143/

Comment: Ups, sorry. Try this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libuuid1:i386`

Comment: @A.B. no success -   `Unable to locate package libuuid1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27044/discussion-between-a-b-and-nirmik).

Answer (score 1):

Before you start, try to delete unneeded packaged using :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now, you have to install all dependencies packages using :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

After that, try to install updates using :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: already tried all this... does not work

Comment: Have you tried to perform check on apt-get ?
`sudo apt-get check`
This should check for any broken dependencies and should fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the main server instead of `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`

```
sudo sed -i 's://in\.://:g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

or change the server via *Software & Updates*. Select <kbd>Main server</kbd> for <kbd>Download from</kbd>:

[image]

---

Install the correct version of `libuuid1:i386`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libuuid1:i386=2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.6
```

But I believe a

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-ugrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libuuid1:i386
```

will be enough, as the needed version is in the Ubuntu repositories (trusty-updates).

Check if you have enabled <kbd>Recommended updates (trusty-updates)</kbd> in *Software & Updates*. The screenshot is for  Vivid, therefore in your Ubuntu *vivid* is replaced by *trusty*

[image]

Comment: both not working.
   `E: Internal Error, No file name for libuuid1:amd64`    error for 1st command and `E: Unable to locate package libuuid1` for 2nd